# Chinese Dharmaguptaka jurisprudence with regards to homosexual seminarians

Tags: ordination

Has there been a recent monastic ruling amongst Dharmaguptaka monks in China & Hong Kong with regards to a policy of denying ordination to laymen who have lived homosexual lifestyles prior to cultivating the aspiration to go forth?

Comment: Let us not debate over whether or not homosexuality is "right" or "wrong" or whether or not this was a skillful jurisprudence. If we simply pool our resources to generate information, that will be enough.